# Generate a List/Set by preprocessor/template from different modules and has to be filled before linking

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I have some global variables (classes) that as I understand have created before `main()` call. I need some technique to add data to a List of something either global or as member of that class from any part of my code and it have to be filled before Linker. To use it inside globally created classes. Is it possible? I did not find any similar solution or even question, so any help will be appreciated.

Detailed example:

I've have singleton class which has a variable that was filled in the constructor. All other classes use data from the class at run time someone early someone later. Singleton class is created at the begin of main function. I am using singleton in different projects, data that it has  mostly universal for all projects and modules except special flag which should show requirement for this module. If singleton throw exception program exits and we know it at the first steps of execution because singleton creates at first lines of the main. So singleton has a lot of universal data for all projects but I need to add flags to point for singleton which data is required for each module. I have created template for main so for each project I have the same main with just simple define PROJECT_NAME later I add .cpp to the project and they have to register which data is required and which not.

This explanation not looks like perfect, if it is not understandable don't hesitate to say it I will organize it more deliberately.

Edited:

I'm still looking for solution in the Internet, and found constexpr it looks like what I need, but at this moment it is not supported by all compilers, is there some workaround ?

Comment: that sounds like an XY question coupled with great confusion. please describe the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to not use global variables, but instead use static variables within a global function.  The first time the function is called the variable will be initialized and then have the function return a reference to the varaible.

```
my_class& instnace() {
   static my_class i;
   return i;
}
```

A list example:

```
std::list<my_class>& global_list() { 
   static std::list<my_class> m; return m;
}


static int x = []()->int{ global_list().push_back(my_class); return 0;}();
```

Comment: Bytemaster thank your for operative response. Could you give more comprehensive explanation for your list example, I do not understand how I can use it. To be more precise I cant understand static int x... part. Thanks.

Comment: I've found information about lambda function. The problem is if I do it inside other class then information will be added when I'll call constructor or function. It means that original class was already created and passed all data as correct.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Instead of a lambda, you could just define a helper function.

Comment: An ugly example what I want to reiceve.
`in main.cpp
vector<string> param_list;
`

Comment: `first.cpp:

void addList1(void)
{
param_list.push_back("first");
}

void a___1234=1addList();
`

Comment: `second.cpp:

void addList2(void)
{
param_list.push_back("second");
}

void a___12345=addList2();
`

Comment: addList1 and addList2 will be called before main and populate correct param_list - so later inside main I can analyse it.

Comment: Ahh, actually you are doing the same, I'm going to try your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish what you want from different modules , one of the way is to have things done is some sort of callback function when your dll is loaded.

One windows it is **[DLLMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

> An optional entry point into a dynamic-link library (DLL). When the
>   system starts or terminates a process or thread, it calls the
>   entry-point function for each loaded DLL using the first thread of the
>   process. The system also calls the entry-point function for a DLL when
>   it is loaded or unloaded using the LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary
>   functions.

On other platforms with gcc you can get by the [attribute constructor]

> constructor The constructor attribute causes the function to be called
>   automatically before execution enters main (). Similarly, the
>   destructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically
>   after main () has completed or exit () has been called. Functions with
>   these attributes are useful for initializing data that will be used
>   implicitly during the execution of the program. These attributes are
>   not currently implemented for Objective-C.

**Warning**

It is very easy to shoot yourself in the foot with this method. At least on windows that are lot of things you cannot do in the [dll entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx). Please read your compiler/os documentation to see what the limitations are.